# Candidate sampling for softmax neural networks in mathematica

Tags: data, machine-learning, neural-networks

Though I've been using mathematica for a few years, I've never really delved into its ML capabilities (except for the occasional clustering). I'm curious if anyone who has some experience using mathematica's Neural Networks has done anything with [candidate sampling](https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/candidate_sampling.pdf) with a softmax output, and if so, how one might go about doing it.

Comment: I checked all the methods for `Predict[]` including `Method -> "NeuralNetwork"` on tasks from the site https://www.kaggle.com/ . The result is always very average. It is possible that we can improve to good by simply using Wolfram's language. But I did not try.

Comment: @ericmarkmartin It would be useful if you could add some sample data and output to your question, to make it easier to test an answer. Have you tried anything specifically? `SoftmaxLayer` would be a good place to start :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm not certain that your comment is relevant to the question. The `Predict` functionality is quite apart from the much lower-level Neural Networks framework.

Comment: @CarlLange Then indicate which level you want to check and give an example.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I didn't write the question. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, everyone. I am working with the new_york_citibike dataset available for free in Google's Public Dataset repository in BigQuery. My goal is to try to predict which station a bike will end up at given it's starting position, time of day, etc. However, there are 814 outputs, which is a lot for softmax. That's why I'm asking about using candidate sampling. I'm well aware that softmax is available in Mathematica, but I didn't see anything about training using candidate sampling.

Comment: @ericmarkmartin I did a bit of research and it looks to me like candidate sampling might need to be implemented within the built-in softmax layer, which you may want to put in a feature request for Wolfram. You might have some luck with [NCE loss](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/example/nce-loss) though, which you might be able to implement as a LossFunction and should address the same problem. On a separate note, I haven't had a major problem with SoftmaxLayer and 431 classes, but I admit improving performance would be nice.

Comment: @ericmarkmartin: 814 classes is fairly small. The net underpinning ImageIdentify (https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Wolfram-ImageIdentify-Net-V1) has over 3000 classes, and the softmax doesn't cause any major performance issues. It would be nice to have some approximate softmax for NLP though (where you often have language +30,000 tokens).